# Tensorflow TextVectorization brings None shape in model.summary()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using an `encoder` from using the `TextVectorization` object from `preprocessing` class. I then adapt my train data like so:

```
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(max_tokens=1000)
encoder.adapt(dataset_all.map(lambda text, label: text))
```

I then want to run a simple neural network with dense layers. Here is my model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                  tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string),
                  encoder,
                  tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(encoder.get_vocabulary())+1
                           ,output_dim=64,mask_zero=True),
                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])
```

When I print the summary I get the following:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
text_vectorization (TextVect multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_39 (Embedding)     (None, None, 64)          6142528   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_74 (Dense)             (None, None, 64)          4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_75 (Dense)             (None, None, 4)           260       
=================================================================
Total params: 6,146,948
Trainable params: 6,146,948
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I don't understand what the second `None` in each of the output dims represents. Also, when I try to fit the model, I get an error saying (am using `sparseCategoricalCrossEntropy` loss ):

```
assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [64 1] [y (sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [64 69]
```

Since I need a 2D output for the final dense layer, I tried adding a flatten layer after the embedding layer, however it doesn't work since the second dimension of the dense's input is unspecified.

If I add a RNN layer after my embedding layer, the network trains correctly since the output of the embedding layer is 3D, however, I don't understand how to only have the dense layers.

Comment: What about adding `GlobalAveragePooling1D` after embedding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't specified the argument that indicates what the output shape of `encoder` will be, i.e `output_sequence_length`.

> **output_sequence_length:** If set, the output will have its time dimension padded or truncated to exactly output_sequence_length values, resulting in a tensor of shape [batch_size, output_sequence_length] regardless of how many tokens resulted from the splitting step. Defaults to None.

If you set it to a number, you will see that the output shape of the layer will be defined:

```
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=1000, 
    output_sequence_length=200
)
```

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
text_vectorization_3 (TextVe (None, 200)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 200, 64)           448       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 200, 64)           4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 200, 4)            260       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,868
Trainable params: 4,868
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

After that, you can use a `GlobalAveragePooling1D` layer to have 2D output.

Read the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/TextVectorization)